# Can I import a dll for one class only?

Tags: vb.net, class, dll, import, reference

Good day,

I have used dll imports for "user32.dll" in the past.
However, I am trying to import a class library into my application which has some namespaces which come into conflict with namespaces which are already imported and referenced from other class libraries.

How can I reference this dll and only use the namespaces contained in it, or override the other namespaces imported from other class libraries in one class without it affecting the rest of the application.

I am still pretty new, this may not be possible.

Thank you.

Comment: Well you cannot use single function imports (like with `user32.dll`) with libraries generated by .NET (or COM compat. for that matter) since most of them do not provide the required `entry points`. So if your target lib does not provide entry points, you'll have to reference it entiraly and access it's objects via the global path.

Comment: There in lies my issues. If I import this particular dll into my assembly it contains competing namespaces and classes with ones already in my application. This causes major issues. I was hoping I could load the assembly and call functions from it as needed without referencing it in my application. I could go into exactly what I am tying to do if that could help with any ideas...

Comment: Well then check out the alias construct: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173212.aspx
  and/or the using keyword: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179630/what-is-aliases-for-in-reference-properties-in-visual-studio

Comment: Excellent! Thank you for the direction sir. Would this method of "using" also work in vb.net with "import"?

Comment: Sorry, new question of relevance: I still have to reference the dll in vb.net. Although your first link explains it in cs, I am still having issue as to how to reference it using Visual Basic. I do apologize and appreciate your help.

Comment: Well in vb.net you'll have **Imports** [Alias = ] NAMESPACE instaed of `using` ^^ (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f38zh8x.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the relevant issues:

In `VB.NET` one can use the [Declare](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4zey12w5.aspx) statement to call win32 functions in DLL's with typical EntryPoint constructs.

.NET Assemblies do not provide classical Win32 type EntryPoints (as such they cannot be 'declared')

If one needs to reference a .NET Assembly [or COM] you need to add a reference to the target library when compiling (usually done in the VS IDE or with the `/r:` switch)

In some cases Namespaces of such referenced Assemblies may collide with others. (i.E. referencing the same Assembly in different versions)

In that case one needs to import the required (conflicting) Namespaces with an [Alias](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f38zh8x.aspx)

For example:

Assuming you have an assembly with a root namespace `Net` that could collide with `System.Net` use:

```
Imports System
Imports ExtNet = SomeNetworkAssembly
```

Then in this case to access members of that assembly use `ExtNet` instead of `Net`

Note you can name the `ExtNet` part as you wish.

In C# one can do it via the `using` keyword instead.